# Condition based on current model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have here a model helper named GmailGcalendar

I have multiple actions in 2 models namely gmail.rb and pivotaltracker.rb

They do the same functions, but the only difference is the connection url.

In my lib helper:

```
def connection_url
    if API::Pivotaltracker
      'https://www.pivotaltracker.com'
    else
      'https://accounts.google.com'
    end
  end

  def my_connections
    connection_name ||= Faraday.new(:url => "#{connection_url}" , ssl: {verify: false}) do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
    end
    puts "@@@@"
    puts connection_url
  end
```

And in my gmail.rb

```
def connection
    my_connections
end
```

As well as my pivotaltracker.rb

```
def connection
    my_connections
end
```

Now they have different connection url.

Pivotal goes to https://www.pivotaltracker.com
Gmail goes to https://accounts.google.com

But I seem to can't make the condition work in connection_url action.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am using the connection_url here: ( in the Faraday block )

```
def my_connections
    connection_name ||= Faraday.new(:url => "#{connection_url}" , ssl: {verify: false}) do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
    end
    puts "@@@@"
    puts connection_url
  end
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what are you trying to accomplish, please expand. When do you want to choose each url?

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post.

Comment: Read your question again. Nowhere are you asking anything. What's the question? "seem to can't make the condition work" doesn't tell me anything I can use to help!

Comment: Sorry. Just trying a conditional approach if class is this and class is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can rewrite your lib helper as class:

```
class Connection
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def setup
    connection_name ||= Faraday.new(:url => "@url" , ssl: {verify: false}) do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
    end
  end
end
```

Now in the model you can initialize this class with the url you want, for example:

```
def connection
    Connection.new("https://accounts.google.com").setup
end
```

I didn't test this code, but it should work.

Comment: thanks let me try this one. How about when pivotaltracker is the action/class?